# SWT - Column value is a boolean

Tags: java, swt

When setting up column values in my Table Viewer.
How do you address columns that are not string values?
How would I change the code below to address a boolean value instead of String value?

Here is the code I am using to layout the rest of the columns with String values.

```
col = createTableViewerColumn(titles[5], bounds[5], 5);
   col.setLabelProvider(new ColumnLabelProvider() {
      public String getText(Object element) {
         if(element instanceof AplotResultsDataModel.ResultsData) {
            return ((AplotResultsDataModel.ResultsData)element).getPrintStatus();
         }          
      return super.getText(element); 
      }
   });
```

`getPrintStatus()` returns a `boolean` value

Comment: `Boolean.toString()`?  `return getPrintStatus() ? "True" : "False"`?

Answer (score 0):

I would suggest  you to use `ColumnLabelProvider.getImage(Object element)` and show status image there.